# can we change the vector into matrix in numpy with the elements in the vector repeats in a matrix with m*n dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, numba

```
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.vectorize('i4(i4)', target = 'parallel')
def mag(b):

    return b * b

 def main():

    mat_a = np.full((5, 3),2,dtype=np.int32)

    c = mag(mat_a)

    d = np.sum(c, axis = 1)

    print d
```

OUTPUT: `[12 12 12 12 12]`

But I want the output to be like this:

```
[12 12 12]
[12 12 12]
[12 12 12]
[12 12 12]
[12 12 12]
```

Clear example:

Suppose I have a output like this: `[12 13 14 15 16]` I want to convert each element in the vector into my own dimensions with numpy

```
[[12 12 12]
 [13 13 13]
 [14 14 14]
 [15 15 15]
 [16 16 16]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly you could simply use `np.repeat` and  `reshape`:

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> arr = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> n = 3
>>> np.repeat(arr, n).reshape(-1, arr.size)
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4]])
```

In case the result doesn't need to be writable you could also use `np.broadcast_to` and transpose:

```
>>> n = 7
>>> np.broadcast_to(arr, (n, arr.size)).T
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]])
```